# TileMIll FileGDB Annotations

Tags: labeling, tilemill, annotation, file-geodatabase, cartocss

Now that TileMill (specifically TileMill-v0.10.1-291-g31027ed) supports FileGDB https://www.mapbox.com/blog/tilemill-adds-support-for-esri-filegdb-format/ ...Is it possible to add label annotations that were created in ArcGIS to TileMill? I added a gdb containing some highway shields as annotations and they imported into TileMill but show up as square polygons (probably from the default styling option). I just wasn't sure if I'm supposed to be styling them based on a marker, shield, etc. or if styling them is a lost cause because TileMill fails to support annotated labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by @springmeyer from Mapbox:

"Hi @ANDYGA811 - thanks for getting in touch and sharing your experience.

It appears that the annotation layer is coming through as polygons, which is fine. What you can do then is apply a text or shield style rather than a polygon style.

So, the "Save & style" button you pressed when saving the layer in TileMill likely added something like:

polygon-opacity:1;
  polygon-fill:#ae8;
Try removing those lines and replacing with something like:

shield-name:"[NAME]";
  shield-face-name:"DejaVu Sans Book";
  shield-file:url("path/to/icon.svg");
This assumes your annotation layer has field attributes of NAME for the 75 value in the shields and you have the shield icons as png or svg available somewhere on your filesystem."

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox FGDB support builds off of the [OpenFileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_openfilegdb.html) driver from GDAL.  There is nothing to indicate that it supports annotations, as those are largely a specific interpretation of an ESRI schema that defines how the labels should look based on tabular data and geometry, not raw geometry made to look like the text.